# Integrate SAML with a GraphQL Node.js server already using JWT

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, jwt, saml

I have a Node.js GraphQL server built using `apollo-server` running in production for the past one year. Authorization is handled by means of the `graphql-shield` library and JWT tokens in the request `Authorization` header.

Now, we have a new enterprise client and they want to log in via SAML using their server as IdP and obviously, ours will be the SP.

How can I send back a JWT token to the client once the SAML authentication is successfully completed? What is the right way to do handle this sort of a situation so I don't have to re-architecture how we handle authorization throughout our server and continue using JWT?

Answer (score 1):

In case of successful authentication IP will send SAML token to the application.

From that SAML token fetch identifier (example emailAddress) for that user and create JWT for user (using identifier) and redirect the user to application by using JWT.